# PHP: Simple, Validate if string is hex?

Tags: php, encryption, binary, hex

I have no clue how to validate this string. I am simply supplying an IV for an encryption, but can find no 1is_hex()1 or similar function, I can’t wrap my head around it! I read on a comment in the php documentation (user contrib. notes) this:

```
if($iv == dechex(hexdec($iv))) {
  //True
} else {
  //False
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work at all.. It only says false.
If it helps my input of my IV would be this:

```
92bff433cc639a6d
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Use function :  [ctype_xdigit](http://php.net/ctype_xdigit)

```
<?php
$strings = array('AB10BC99', 'AR1012', 'ab12bc99');
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_xdigit($testcase)) {
        echo "The string $testcase consists of all hexadecimal digits.\n";
    } else {
        echo "The string $testcase does not consist of all hexadecimal digits.\n";
    }
}
?>
```

The above example will output:

- The string `AB10BC99` consists of all hexadecimal digits.
- The string `AR1012` does not consist of all hexadecimal digits.
- The string `ab12bc99` consists of all hexadecimal digits.

Comment: Thank you! I just dislike using regex sometimes, I'm glad there was something barebone there. Must look more in the list of functions next time.

Comment: Deprecated: `ctype_xdigit()`

Comment: @Zortext Documentation at php.net says that only submitting non-strings as input is deprecated, and that input values should be cast as such prior to use.

Answer (score 9):

Another way without `ctype` or `regex`:

```
$str = 'string to check';

if (trim($str, '0..9A..Fa..f') == '') {
    // string is hexadecimal
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Is there any reason not to match against a simple RE like "[0-9A-Fa-f]+"? (edit: possibly with a '^' at the beginning and '$' at the end to assure you've matched the whole string).

Comment: I tried, 

    $iv = "92bff433cc63da6W"
    if(preg_match('/[0-9A-Fa-f]+/', $iv)) {
    $enc = mcrypt_encrypt( MCRYPT_BLOWFISH, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, pack("H*",$iv));
      $ENCRSLT = bin2hex($enc);
    } else {
      $ENCRSLT = "Error: Key or IV is not Hexidecimal. Valid characters: 0-9a-f.";
    } 

But it doesn't validate (the obvious W at the end)

Comment: Go for the regexp: "^[0-9a-f]$" as suggested by Jerry. And drop the upper-case A-F as it is not supported according to the error message you pasted.

Comment: Alrighty, It works perfectly. I was actually going to try that myself, guess I'm not too bad at regex myself. Thanks

Comment: better to find alone non-range character than check whole sting.

Answer (score 4):

The perfect way to check HEX string works from PHP 4 and above.

```
<?php
function is_hex($hex_code) {
        return @preg_match("/^[a-f0-9]{2,}$/i", $hex_code) && !(strlen($hex_code) & 1);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your input is too large. From the PHP manual of [dexhex](http://fi.php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)

> The largest number that can be converted is 4294967295 in decimal
>   resulting to "ffffffff"

So you'll be better off using a RegEx, which have already been supplied here by others.

Comment: The hex was an 8 byte string for the IV rather than a number, regex and better ctype_xdigit did the job.

Answer (score 1):

Add the case-insensitive 'i' flag

```
preg_match('/^[0-9a-f]+$/i', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible and quite simple

```
$a="affe";  //is_hex
$b="a0bg";   //is_not_hex

if(is_numeric('0x'.$a)) echo 'is_hex';
else echo 'is_not_hex';

if(is_numeric('0x'.$b)) echo 'is_hex';
else echo 'is_not_hex';
```

Comment: No longer allowed in PHP 7, see "Hexadecimal strings are no longer considered numeric" http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php